# Dropdown submenu same width as main menu bar

Tags: css, navigation

I'm new to CSS, and if I'm honest don't really know what I'm doing. For a while now I've been trying to make the child page on the dropdown menu to be at least the same width as the parent page.

After hours of being frustrated that nothing I find on google works, I figured that I should ask someone who actually knows what they're doing. This is the (awful) code:

```
.menu li > a:after {
    color: #fff;
    content: ' ▼';
}

.menu li > a:only-child:after {
    content: '';
}



#main-nav {
    background-color: #6699FF;
    height: 40px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
}

#main-nav li {
    position: relative;
}

#main-nav ul {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    position: relative;
    list-style: none;
    display: block;
}

#main-nav ul li {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
}

#main-nav ul li a {
    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    display: inline;
}


#main-nav a:link, #main-nav a:visited {
    color: #FFF;
    display: block;
    padding: 10px 25px;
    height: 20px;
}



/*Sub menus */


#main-nav {
    overflow: visible;
}

#main-nav ul {
    right: 0;
}

#main-nav ul li ul.sub-menu {
    position:absolute;
    display:none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0!Important;
    float: none;
}

#main-nav ul li:hover ul.sub-menu {
    display:block!important;
    float: none;
    white-space: nowrap;

}

#main-nav ul li ul.sub-menu li {
    background: #6699FF;
    text-align: left;
    -webkit-transition: height 0.3s ease-in;
            -moz-transition: height 0.3s ease-in;
            -o-transition: height 0.3s ease-in;
            -ms-transition: height 0.3s ease-in;
            transition: height 0.3s ease-in;
    width: auto;
    left:0;
}
#main-nav ul li ul.sub-menu li a {
    width: auto;
    border-radius: 0px;
    -moz-border-radius: 0px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0px;
}
```

This is what it looks like when I hover over the parent 'meep' page:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/djiiY.png

I would like it to be the same width, starting from the left so that any excess width due to a long page name would go to the right.

I've tried changing the display type and widths, nothing yet :(

I'd greatly appreciate any help! Thanks in advance

and sorry for the terrible code

JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/q5381Ly5/1/

Comment: A fiddle would be helpful. http://jsfiddle.net/ Paste your code their and share the link.

Comment: Show some of your markup

Comment: Struggling to create a working jsfiddle as I'm using wordpress; the index.php isn't normal html

Comment: Here http://jsfiddle.net/q5381Ly5/

Comment: Updated it http://jsfiddle.net/q5381Ly5/1/

Comment: Having trouble visualizing what you want. You don't want each individual dropdown to adhere to it's parent and inherit their width - rather, have it absolutely positioned to the left, full width, below the navigation?

Comment: No, sorry I badly worded it. I do want the dropdown to inherit the parent width, just not sure how to do it. As for the positioning, at the moment it's on the right; I'm trying to get it to be on the left, with the parent width as the minimum/ideal width.

Comment: No worries - I suck at reading. Have you tried adjusting `#main-nav ul { left: 0; width: 100%; }` ? And then set it's `<li>` to `width: 100%;` ? ( need to remove `right: 0;` )

Comment: Just did after wlin wrote his answer, thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I only change these two, add width 100%, it will get the whole width of the parent.

here is a demo http://jsfiddle.net/q5381Ly5/4/

```
    #main-nav ul li:hover ul.sub-menu {
        display:block!important;
        float: none;
        white-space: nowrap;
        width:100%;
    }

    #main-nav ul li ul.sub-menu li {
        width:100%;
        background: #6699FF;
        text-align: left;
        -webkit-transition: height 0.3s ease-in;
                -moz-transition: height 0.3s ease-in;
                -o-transition: height 0.3s ease-in;
                -ms-transition: height 0.3s ease-in;
                transition: height 0.3s ease-in;
        left:0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having width `auto` to your submenu do change it to `100%`